# py.test : logging the number of failures

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Can I catch the failures found by `py.test` ? I would like to build a log where I will write the numbers of failures and also the OS tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `--resultlog` which @srowland showed, you can also use `--junitxml` to write a JUnit XML file, or [write your own plugin](https://pytest.org/latest/writing_plugins.html) to log in a custom format.

Comment: This is more powerful. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can log a machine readable result file for this purpose using:

```
py.test --resultlog=path
```

Documentation [is available here](https://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#creating-resultlog-format-files). This file is what many other tools use to inspect the output of a `py.test` run and, for example, compare results between different runs.

Comment: I love more and more `py.test`. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right documentation.